# Use PROC SQL to select null when two conditions are met

Tags: sql, sas

I am running a code where i am creating a table by taking all the columns from a table and then adding two columns from a second table. In the case when the two values coming from the second table are equal to 0 i need to set them to null. I can have other combinations such as `FIELD1 = 0` and `FIELD1 = 1` for example but not both equal to 0.

I am using `PROC SQL` like this:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE TABLEA  AS 
        SELECT A.*,
            CASE 
                WHEN (B.FIELD1 NE 0 AND B.FIELD2 NE 0)
                THEN B.FIELD1
            ELSE .
            END 
        AS FIELD1,
            CASE 
                WHEN (B.FIELD2 NE 0 AND B.FIELD1 NE 0)
                THEN B.FIELD2
            ELSE .
            END 
        AS FIELD2
            FROM TABLE1 AS A
                LEFT JOIN TABLE2 AS B ON A.ID = B.ID;
QUIT;
```

The code i am showing is not working, i still see a lot of records where `FIELD1 = 0` and `FIELD2 = 0` in the resulting table `TABLEA`.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Does TABLEA already have variables named FIELD1 and FIELD2?  When there are multiple variables with the same name then the CREATE TABLE/VIEW in PROC SQL will only keep the first one it sees.

Comment: @Tom i delete the columns before so i don't end up with the ones i already have.

Comment: @Tom actually you are right, it was taking values that were already on the table. That would do it thanks.

Comment: @blidt Please put that as an answer, and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i need to make sure that the variables don't already exist otherwise it will just keep the existing ones and cause this confusion.